# CHtml Link returns null for parent

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, yii, yii-components

I created a url using Chtml::Link like this:

```
CHtml::link("Remove", '#', array('class' => 'delete')))
```

Now, when user clicks it i send a ajax request like this:

```
$('.delete').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
      url:'" . $this->createUrl('//shop/shoppingCart/delete') . "',
      type : 'GET',
      data: {id: $position},
      success: function(result) {
         console.log($(this).parent());
      },
     });
});
```

it always logs "`undefined`" but the link is inside a `td`
What i want to do is remove the row containing the link. Any new approach is also welcome. Please help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`this` inside the success function of the ajax call is another `this` than the `this` in the click function. So, you probably can't find the parent of that `this`.

I guess you are trying to find the parent of the element to update the html right? Why don't you use Chtml::ajaxLink instead, then you can use the update property:

```
Chtml::ajaxLink(
    'Remove',
    $this->createUrl('//shop/shoppingCart/delete'),
    array(
        'update' => "$('.delete').parent()", // or anything like this
        'data' => array(
            'id' => $position,
        )
    ),
    array(
        'class' => 'delete'
    )
)
```